# Checkbox - Fire one function when checked and fire another when not checked

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I created a page where users can make selections with checkboxes. When items are checked, I am adding their `ID`s to an array, `selecteddocs`. When they are unchecked, I'd like to remove the item from the array. How can I trigger a function to remove the item(s) when it detects the checkbox has been unchecked?

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Document Group</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let doc of docs">
    <td><input type="checkbox" (click)="select(doc.ID)"></td>
    <td>{{doc.DocumentGroup}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Description}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the TS:

```
  selectedqr;
  selecteddocs = [];

  select(ID){
    this.selectedqr = ID;
    console.log(this.selectedqr);
    this.selecteddocs.push(ID);
    console.log(this.selecteddocs);
  }

//On Uncheck: var index = selecteddocs.indexOf(ID);
              selecteddocs.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Angular has a `change` event handler for checkboxes and radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the value of the checkbox on the change event.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="doc.selected" (change)="select(doc.ID, doc.selected)"></td>
```

then run the appropriate function depending what doc.selected gives you.

Comment: This should work, however when I use `console.log(selected)` in the function, it returns as `undefined` when checked and `true` when unchecked. Why? Shouldn't this be in reverse?

Comment: Your "doc" object has to have a field called selected in it. A boolean value.

Comment: So, I would add `selected: boolean = true` to the controller to do this?

Comment: *ngFor="let doc of docs" ... Where are docs defined. You need to add a field, "selected" in this case, to the doc object. This wouldnt be added to the controller, because all doc objects would then share the same checkbox value. each object needs its own value for whether it is selected or not.

Comment: So, `doc.selected: boolean = true`?

Comment: right, every doc needs a "selected" field. So wherever you define or retrieve docs map a "selected" field to the object